# Error message "app.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: window.addEventListner is not a function at app.js:1"

Tags: javascript

I am getting below error while adding my below javascript code

```
window.addEventListner('load',()=> {
    let long;
    let lat;
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            console.log(position);
        } )
        }else {
            console.log("ISSUE")
;
    };
});
```

Error message:-

app.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: window.addEventListner is not a function
at app.js:1

Please help

Comment: Use instead `window.onload `

Comment: Its a typo. addEventListener

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get accurate answers, you need to specify what you're looking for, the portion(s) of code that are throwing issues for you and explain what you've been trying to achieve as well what you've already tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled `Listener` in the function name.